# How to select img src attribute inside a div?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

What selector do I need to use to get the src value of this picture?

```
<div class="rg-image">
    <img src="/zenphoto/cache/test2/6244146_460s_595_watermark.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried and how did it fail to fulfil your needs? What does this precise picture have that makes it unique among others?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There might be better ways to do this, but without seeing more of the markup, I would recommend using something like this:

```
var img_src  = $( '.rg-image > img' ).attr( 'src' );
```

This selector will match `<img>` tags only within the first level of any element containing the `.rc-image` class.

**Note:**
This assumes that there is only one `<img>` element contained within one `.rg-image` element. You won't be able to retrieve multiple `src` attributes in this way as the selector will match many elements. You'll need to loop over the matches and for each one extract the `src` attribute.

Answer (score 11):

There are several ways to do it.

You can do this

```
var src  = $('.rg-image img').attr('src');
```

or

```
 var src $('.rg-image').find('img').attr('src');
```

or

```
var src=$('.rg-image').children("img").attr('src');
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fRUUd/1503/)

As @Broxzier mentioned in comment,use `prop` instead of `attr`,If you are updating `src`

Comment: that's better with a dot

Comment: `.prop()` is the new `.attr()`.

Comment: @Broxzier Yeah,That's a point :) Updated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.rg-image img').attr('src');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try by following code:

```
var source=$('.rg-image').children("img").attr('src');
```